# Number of possible solutions to $X^2 = 1$ in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to find the number of solutions to the equation $X^2 = 1$ that could exist in any ring $R$. I am unsure how to approach this question but below is what I came up with:

If the ring is without unity, then there are no solutions.
If the ring has $1 = 0$ then there is just one solution, namely $0$.
If the ring has $1 \neq 0$ then we can write the equation as $X^2 - 1 = 0$ and factorise to $(X-1)(X+1)=0$. Now $R$ could be a domain, or it could have zero divisors. In the former case, we have two solutions ($1$ and $-1$) and in the latter there could possibly be infinitely many zero divisors of $R$ (e.g. if $R$ = $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$) so there could be infinitely many solutions to this equation.

I'm not sure the argument or the answer is correct.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825642/ring-with-four-solutions-to-x2-1-0?rq=1

Comment: It may be related in the sense that it's the same equation and a particular case of 4 solutions is discussed, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If I thought it would answer your question I'd have flagged your question as duplicate.

Comment: Probably also relevant: [An equation of form $x^{2}+ax+b=0$ might have infinite amount of solutions in a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962422/an-equation-of-form-x2axb-0-might-have-infinite-amount-of-solutions-in-a?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, if $R$ has no zero divisors, there are at most two solutions: $1$ and $-1$ (possibly the same).

If $R$ has infinitely many zero divisors, this does not necessarily imply that there are infinitely many solutions. E.g. for $R=\mathbb Z^2$, there are only four solutions $(\pm1,\pm1)$.

In general, if $P\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is a polynomial and $n_R$ denotes the number of zeroes of $P$ in $R$, then $n_{R\times S}=n_R\cdot n_S$ for any rings $R$ and $S$.

A dull example of a ring with infinitely many solutions would thus be $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio As far as I know the infinite number of solutions is of $x^2=-1$. In *any* ring without zero divisors, the solutions of $x^2=1$ are two, except if the characteristic is $2$, when there's just one.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I misunderstood the minus one there...